# Changing Case of Strings (Lower to Upper) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 databases, one with lowercase data and another with uppercase data.

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(40)
SELECT @NAME = UPPER(SELECT NAME FROM DELETED)
```

By executing `SELECT NAME FROM DELETED`, I am selecting data that is lower case.

By executing `SELECT @NAME = UPPER(SELECT NAME FROM DELETED)`, I would want to select uppercase data on the query inside the UPPER().

Question is can I use the UPPER() with the SELECT, like the query above?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT UPPER(NAME) FROM DELETED
```

instead of

```
UPPER(SELECT NAME FROM DELETED)
```

Comment: if use the query above, wont it select the the uppercase data? from the table DELETED, it only contain lowercase data. And in return it will return no result? *the table is casesensitive

Comment: @allen, UPPER is a function that affects the data, not a selection criteria.  So, no it won't only return data that is already upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT @pNAME = UPPER([NAME]) FROM DELETED
```

Comment: if use the query above, wont it select the the uppercase data? from the table DELETED, it only contain lowercase data. And in return it will return no result? *the table is casesensitive

Comment: No, it will not.  Upper takes whatever it's given and forces it to be upper case.  if Name is lower, it will stay lower.  Upper just displays it for you as upper.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an extra pair of brackets

Select @NAME = UPPER((SELECT NAME FROM DELETED));

(Not that I'd do it that way, see Lukas's answer for a better approach).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this was possible! So `UPPER` also accepts `TABLE` or `CURSOR` types in SQL server?

Comment: @Lukas: No, that's what the extra brackets are for; they turn the results of the select into a scalar value.

Comment: @EdHarper: Right, and upon reflection I should have mentioned that.